# SQL Server Function Fails, logic seems good

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This SQL Function returns 0 no matter what the input, where did I screw up ?
The idea is to return a string or a date indicating the last day of February with a four digit year as input

```html
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LastDayOfFeb] 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 --This returns the last day of February by figuring out when leap year occurs
 
--Leap years are those years that are evenly divisible by 4, except for  
--centennial years (those ending in -00), which receive the extra  
--day only if they are evenly divisible by 400 
-- Input SMALLINT , Output DATE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (@Year SMALLINT) 
returns VARCHAR

AS 
  BEGIN 
  set @year = cast(@year as smallint)
      --1. ______________Not a multiple of 4 -------------------------> NO 
      IF @Year % 4 <> 0 
        RETURN '0228' + Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR) 

      --2. ______________A multiple of 4 but NOT Centennial ----------> YES 
      IF @Year % 4 <> 0 
        RETURN '0229' + Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR)

      --3. ______________A Centennial and a multiple of 400 ----------> YES 
      IF @Year % 400 = 0 
        RETURN '0229' + Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR)

      --4. ______________A Centennial but NOT a multiple of 400 ------> NO 
      RETURN '0228' + Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR)
  END  
GO
```

Comment: Why on earth do you need a function to calculate the last day in February? Why do need the last day in February? Are you doing a date range query? So just say >= Feb 1 and < Mar 1.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing `RETURN VARCHAR` with `RETURN VARCHAR(10)`. By not specifying the size of the return string, it is assuming a length of 1, which is why you only get the leading '0'.

Comment: +1 https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Well that did the trick ....however I got a logic bug to fix elsewhere as it gave the wrong results on some years

Comment: See if this helps you with your logic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

try

```
declare @year int = 2005
declare @date = dateadd(year, @year - 1900, '19000101')

select @date = dateadd(month, 2, @date)
select @date = dateadd(day, -1, @date)
select @date
```

rather then using strings.

as a function this would be

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LastDayOfFeb]
  (@year SMALLINT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN    
    RETURN dateadd(day, -1,
                   dateadd(month, 2, 
                           dateadd(year, @year - 1900, 0)))

END
```

an example of usage / test

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT year = 2000, last_day_of_feb = dbo.LastDayOfFeb(2000)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT year + 1, dbo.LastDayOfFeb(year + 1)
  FROM cte
  WHERE year + 1 <= 2040
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ebd0c/1)

Comment: I don't follow how to use that syntax as a function